# How can I disable creation of source control in TFS 2010 when creating a new Team Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I've searched MSDN and this site (as well as a pile of web searches) and not found anything obvious ... I do see a similar question here about using an existing source control folder -- and the note that TFS apparently stores some project settings there (and thus needs one whether you use it or not).

We're using a non-TFS source control tool -- and I don't want newcomers "accidentally" storing source versions in TFS.  So, I'd like to disable the creation of a TFS 2010 source control "tree" when I create a new Team Project in VS 2010.

There may be other solutions to this problem, though, and I'm open to suggestion.  For example, if TFS really does need to store some internal data -- how about a way to simply prevent any source code checkins (that is, let TFS use the source control project as needed, but prevent users from adding files)?

Answer (score 3):

TFS has extensive permissions settings.

You should be able restrict check in / access to source tree by permission.

Comment: Sometimes ... it's the simple approach ... I had been looking for something that fit a much bigger hammer.  Totally blew by permissions.  I'll check and see if I can make this work.  I was assuming that the project permissions applied to everything in the project (source control, web access, user stories, etc.) - but your answer makes me think I can be more selective and will look into that.  Thanks!

Comment: I found a Collection-level permission called "Create a Workspace" which says that "Users who have this permission can create a version control workspace."  Looks like I simply remove this permission from the Valid Users group and I should be set.  I can't test this yet, but once I do, I'll report back here.  Thanks!

Comment: One other note - if you haven't already - make sure you get powertools installed on clients and TFS server.  Has some good backup functionality on server side, and all sorts of goodies on client side.  Must have toolset for TFS:

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f